# AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell equivalent for "Launch More Like This"

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

I am using the AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell to write a script. Part of what I would like to do is create a new instance using an existing instance as a template. I know I could just pull the metadata from the instance that I want to use as a template and pass it to New-EC2Instance, but I am looking for an easier way. Does anyone know if there is a AWS PowerShell cmdlet that will enable me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not. You need to explicitly provide your instance attributes.